# searching in an unsorted array in logrithmic time

Tags: arrays, search, big-o

I am currently studying for an exam in Introduction to algorithms, and I came across a question that I can't really solve, the question is this: You have an array of n integers, the first m elements are even, and the remaining elements are odd. You need to write an algorithm that finds the value of m (finds the index of the last even number), and has time complexity of O(log m).

I thought of doing something similar to binary search and simply move left if odd and move right if even until i find the index that is even and his next one is odd, but this thing would work at O(log n) and not O(log m).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start at index 1, then keep on doubling the index, until you find an odd entry. This gives you an upper bound for m in time O(log m). Then do binary search.

Comment: The binary search then could take O(log n) in the worst case. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Abody97 - I obviously meant to do the binary search in the range limited by the previously determined upper bound on m, which is at most 2m. So the binary search is also O(log(m)).

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry about that :) I didn't the fact that the upper bound for `m` is at most `2m`, completely forgot. Sorry again :)